# Trouble grabbing background image url with importxml / xpath

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

I'm trying to scrape some background image urls into a google sheet. Here is an example of the container-

```
<div class="_rs9 _1xcn">
<div class="_1ue-">
<section class="_4gsw _7of _1ue_" style="background-image: url(https://scontent.x.com/v/t64.5771-25/38974906_464042117451453_1752137156853235712_n.png?_nc_cat=100&amp;_nc_ht=scontent.x.com&amp;oh=c19f15536205be2e1eedb7f7fc7cb61b&amp;oe=5C4442FD)">
<div class="_7p2">
</div>
</section>
```

I need to get from the https to the question mark after png. I know there's a way to use substring-before/-after but I am having a tough time, particular with escaping quotes.

Here is my attempt. This just gets me an "#N/A":

```
=IMPORTXML(B2,"substring-before(substring-after(//section[@class='_4gsw _7of _1ue_']/@style, """"background-image: url(""""), """")"""")")
```

Could anyone help with the full importxml statement? Much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach was close. Try the following XPath expression:

```
substring-before(substring-after(//section[@class='_4gsw _7of _1ue_']/@style, 'background-image: url('),'?')
```

The whole expression could look like this:

```
=IMPORTXML(B2,"substring-before(substring-after(//section[@class='_4gsw _7of _1ue_']/@style, 'background-image: url('),'?')")
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It looks like progress, but instead of getting a "#N/A", I get a blank cell. Any idea why?

Comment: I checked it here and it works. So, unfortunately, my answer is _no_

Comment: Figured it out: The answer was coming up blank because the particular section is pulled in from a web request after the page is initially loaded. There's no way to have the importxml statement account for that. I had to find another way using a script. But thank you for the help with the statement. I accepted the answer as correct.